# Which component is handling thread allocation in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

In previous versions of asp.net the framework was responsible for allocating all the threads from thread pool and there was a configuration in the web.config to set it up (maximum number of threads, etc.). So which component is responsible for it in the new ASP.NET? I have not found any special middleware for that, I guess that it should happen even before the middleware, maybe in Kestrel.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The threadpool is a CLR resource that can be configured directly in your Startup https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool%28v=vs.110%29.aspx.

I think what you're actually asking about is configuring how many threads the servers will use to process requests, correct? See https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer/blob/01e9101543906ffd39239efd2f7bb41dbd879902/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel/KestrelServerOptions.cs#L90

Comment: Ok, so it's the Kestrel server configuration only, nothing you can configure in the config.json or something like that (like in web.config before)?

Comment: Correct, it's server specific. If you want kestrel to read it from the conifg then you can open an issue here https://github.com/aspnet/kestrelhttpserver and/or send a PR.

Comment: the link to kestrel configuration is dead. I suggested an edit to update it to the current one, but for some reasons I that I can't understand few ppl wrote "This edit deviates from the original intent of the post". anyway, here is the updated link: https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel/KestrelServerOptions.cs#L91